# Local Time Convert To UTC Time In Hive

Tags: timestamp, hive, utc

I searched a lot on Internet but couldn't find the answer. Here is my question:

I'm writing some queries in Hive. I have a UTC timestamp and would like to change it to UTC time, e.g., given timestamp 1349049600, I would like to convert it to UTC time which is 2012-10-01 00:00:00. However if I use the built in function `from_unixtime(1349049600)` in Hive, I get the local PDT time 2012-09-30 17:00:00.

I realized there is a built in function called `from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)`. Then I tried it like `from_utc_timestamp(1349049600, "GMT")`, the output is 1970-01-16 06:44:09.6 which is totally incorrect.

I don't want to change the time zone of Hive permanently because there are other users. So is there any way I can get a UTC timestamp string from 1349049600 to "2012-10-01 00:00:00"? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 19):

As far as I can tell, `from_utc_timestamp()` needs a date string argument, like `"2014-01-15 11:21:15"`, not a unix seconds-since-epoch value.  That might be why it is giving odd results when you pass an integer?

The only Hive function that deals with epoch seconds seems to be `from_unixtime()` which gives you a timestamp string in the *server timezone*, which I found in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` - `"America/Montreal"` in my case.

So you can get a UTC timestamp string via `to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1389802875),'America/Montreal')`, and then convert to your target timezone with `from_utc_timestamp()`

It all seems very torturous, particularly having to wire your server TZ into your SQL.  Life would be easier if there was a `from_unixtime_utc()` function or something.

---

**Update**: `from_utc_timestamp()` does deal with a *milli*seconds argument as well as a string, but then gets the conversion wrong.

When I try `from_utc_timestamp(1389802875000, 'America/Los_Angeles')` it gives `"2014-01-15 03:21:15"` which is wrong.
The correct answer is `"2014-01-15 08:21:15"` which you can get (for a server in Montreal) via `from_utc_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1389802875),'America/Montreal'), 'America/Los_Angeles')`

Comment: I'm on Hive 0.10.  This looks like this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2867

Answer (score 8):

Hey just wanted to add a little here, I'd suggest trying to "automate" the system timezone.  So instead of statically

```
#STATIC TZ deceleration     
to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1389802875),'America/Montreal')
```

Give this a shot

```
#DYNAMIC TZ
select to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1389802875), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), "z"));
```

This just uses the string output format of "`from_unixtime`" to return the timezone string (lowercase z)

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this :

`to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(timestamp),"PDT")`

Comment: This got an upvote, but it looks like it should be `from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(timestamp),"PDT")`

Comment: @ChrisA. The user wants to convert the time TO utc timezone, that's why this function.

Answer (score 1):

This example provides a solution to the problem of having a hardwired value of the system time zone TZ in your hive code. It was run using hive 0.10.0 in a Centos environment, with OpenJDK java version 1.6. Because it involves time manipulation those precise software revisions might matter. Currently the system is operating in EDT. The table tblFiniteZahl is like a DUAL but with about a million rows, of, you guessed it, finite numbers. But you can substitute any table with at least 1 row. The trick is to format the time in a local timezone but use the z format to capture the timezone and then to extract that value at runtime for passing to the to_utc_timestamp function.

```
select D1,
       D1E,
       D1L,
       D1LT,
       D1LZ,
       to_utc_timestamp(D1LT, D1LZ) as D1UTC
from (
select D1,
       D1E,
       D1L,
       regexp_extract(D1L, '^([^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)[ ](.+)$', 1) as D1LT,
       regexp_extract(D1L, '^([^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)[ ](.+)$', 2) as D1LZ
from (
select D1,
       D1E,
       from_unixtime(D1E, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z') as D1L
from (
select D1,
       unix_timestamp(D1,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z') as D1E
from (
select '2015-08-24 01:15:23 UTC' as D1
from tblFiniteZahl
limit 1
      ) T1
      ) T2
      ) T3
      ) T4
;
```

The result is

```
D1 = 2015-08-24 01:15:23 UTC
DT3 = 1440378923
D1L = 2015-08-23 21:15:23 EDT
D1LT = 2015-08-23 21:15:23
D1LZ = EDT
D1UTC = 2015-08-23 21:15:23
```

This illustrates that the to_utc_timestamp does take a second argument of EDT.

Answer (score -2):

I went to [currentmillis.com](http://currentmillis.com) and pasted 1349049600 without realizing it was actually seconds. And indeed it returned 1970-01-16 in the date, which means that the function you suggested: from_utc_timestamp actually takes milliseconds as the first parameter? Maybe you can try again with `from_utc_timestamp(1349049600000, "GMT")` ?

Comment: I tried that too but the time is still not right...I even saw a post saying that we should multiply the 1349049600000 with a 1.0 (`1349049600000*1.0`), but not working, either..thanks for your help still!

Comment: Can you please try to_utc_timestamp instead? I believe it has the same syntax.