# How to Insert only specific values in a Hive column?

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have the data in the date column = 2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC, Now how to insert this data into a column without the UTC word ? and Hive should recognize this as timestamp datatype

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive convert UTC string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006403/hive-convert-utc-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove UTC using regexp_replace:

```
select timestamp(regexp_replace('2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC','\\s*UTC$',''))
```

Result:

```
2019-10-01 00:00:00.0
```

It is successfully converted to timestamp.