# How can I read in timestamps using spark, save to hive, and have them display correctly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a bunch of records with timestamp columns as strings that look like this:

```
+---------------------+
|         raw         |
+---------------------+
| 2019-07-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-07-04 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-26 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

If I use `.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(Col("raw")))`, and write to hive with a `STRING, TIMESTAMP` schema, then we see:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|         raw         |      timestamp      |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-07-14 00:00:00 | 2019-07-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-07-04 00:00:00 | 2019-07-04 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-26 00:00:00 | 2019-01-26 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But we want the option to specify a source time zone so if we replace to_timestamp with to_utc_timestamp like `.withColumn("timestamp", to_utc_timestamp(Col("raw"), "America/New_York"))`, then we get a table like this with a 5 hour difference:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|         raw         |      timestamp      |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-07-14 00:00:00 | 2019-07-14 05:00:00 |
| 2019-07-04 00:00:00 | 2019-07-04 05:00:00 |
| 2019-01-26 00:00:00 | 2019-01-26 05:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But the server with the data and the hive server is in eastern time zone, so shouldn't we see the timestamp with 0 hours difference?
My question is, how can I load the timestamp from string to hive with a specific time zone, and have it display correctly in hive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local Time Convert To UTC Time In Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278786/local-time-convert-to-utc-time-in-hive)

Comment: Not really, what specifically from there are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that `to_utc_timestamp` converts a timestamp in a **given timezone** to UTC. So if you say that your timestamp is in "America/New_York", then +5 hours is what it will be in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn`t refer wherever your data/hive servers is.
In The example you produced:

```
 .withColumn("timestamp", to_utc_timestamp(Col("raw"), "America/New_York"))
```

it`s actually mean i have timestamp column and i want conver it to UTC,
then you specify the timezone your timestamp column should refer.

so let`s take 2019-07-14 00:00:00 as an example, you are actually say give me this timestamp column in UTC if that timestamp column areazone is America/New_York, so if the time in new york now is 00:00, UTC time is 05:00 (because newyork is UTC -5).

Comment: The hive server and the Hadoop cluster are in the same time zone, EST. My reasoning is that if I use `to_utc_timestamp` with `"America/New_York"` then it should convert `2019-07-14 00:00:00` -> UTC time with EST zone. Then since the hive server is EST it should display as `2019-07-14 00:00:00` because the time zones match (On the column and server), right?