# how to Covert all the timestamps to EST in Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table which contains a timestamp field and it can have any timezone ..(UTC/PST/CST....)
I want to convert all of them to a single timestamp, EST. it can be done either in Hive or Pyspark.
Basically, i am using it in my pyspark application which has a grouping logic on this datetime field and before doing that we want to have all the times in Hive table to be converted to EST time.

Sid

Comment: what have you tried? what does the data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention to the facts which HIV Timezone have limitation on maximum time associates to Y2K38 bugs and JDBC compatibility issue,

> TIMESTAMP type to serde2 that supports unix timestamp (1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC) with optional nanosecond precision using both LazyBinary and LazySimple SerDes.
>   For LazySimpleSerDe, the data is stored in jdbc compliant java.sql.Timestamp parsable strings.
>   [HIV-2272](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2272)
>
> [Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4525) is simulation associates to supporting timestamps earlier than 1970 and later than 2038.
>
> [Hive JDBC doesn't support TIMESTAMP column](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2957)

Therefore, I think will be better if you are using HIV DataType of Date Type or String Type. Then you can use any timezone offset as the default on persistent.

```
* utc_timestamp is the column name */


/* bellow will convert a timestamp in UTC to EST timezone  */

select from_utc_timestamp(utc_timestamp, 'EST') from table1;
```

Hope this helps.

[HIV Data Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types)

Answer (score 0):

Sidd, usually Hive uses the local timezone of the host where the data was written. The function from_utc_timestamp() and to_utc_timestamp can we very helpful. Instead of stating the timezone as UTC/EST you should rather use location/region in that case, since this will account for the day light savings.

Here's a helpful link for more examples: [Local Time Convert To UTC Time In Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278786/local-time-convert-to-utc-time-in-hive)

In case you have further questions, please share what have you already tried and share a sample snippet of your data for investigating further.